# Reference for randomized GMD decoding

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory

The [GMD decoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_minimum-distance_decoding) is an algorithm for decoding concatenated codes up to half their minimal distance. The standard presentation of this algorithm usually proceeds in two steps: First, one shows a randomized decoding algorithm, and proves that this algorithm works *in expectation*, rather than *with high probability*. Then, one uses the latter proof to show how to derandomize the latter algorithm to get an algorithm that always works.

In all the presentations that I could find, it is never shown that the randomized algorithm works with high probability. However, it is not hard to see that this is indeed the case. I need to use this fact, and I wonder whether it was proved somewhere and I can give a reference, or whether I need to prove it myself.

So in short, my question is: Is there a reference for a paper that proves that the randomized decoder works with high probability?